# What’s this connector?

Tags: connector

Can anybody help me with identifying this connector? It’s  off a battery that goes into turtle beach i60 headphones. Thanks a lot. [image]

Comment: Google search "JST Connector" and open the images tab. You will eventually see a similar one.

Comment: Hi thanks eugene i have done but some of them look different kinda looking for a make or model number cheers

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, but only if you promise not to shout at us in the title and capitalise and punctuate properly. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages.

Comment: The JST connectors come in many different sizes (pitches, 1mm, 1.25mm, 2mm, etc) and with different keying and locking options. Try Digikey, they have good images you can compare with.

Comment: WHY ARE WE SCREAMING?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [JST ZHR-3](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/ZHR-3/455-1160-ND/608602)  Would need pitch to verify, however very common.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it and it has dimensions too so you can check.

https://amzn.to/2Dau5I6

[image: 3pin connector 1]

[image: 3pin connector 2]

Comment: Raddevus thats exact measurements but slightly different connector the back on mine is completely flat that 1 has 3 grooves thanks

Comment: Also, amazon is *never* the appropriate source for electronic components. Really.